# PG::ObjectNotInPrerequisiteState: ERROR: cannot insert into view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am extremely confused about an error that I am receiving for one of my controller actions. The error that I receive for one action `positions#one_click_create` yields me this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ObjectNotInPrerequisiteState: ERROR:  cannot insert into view "contributions" DETAIL:  Views that do not select from a single table or view are not automatically updatable.


HINT:  To enable inserting into the view, provide an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger or an unconditional ON INSERT DO INSTEAD rule.
    : INSERT INTO "contributions" ("person_id", "project_id", "position_id", "name_fact_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"
        test/controllers/positions_controller_test.rb:420:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>
```

The error goes on to suggest a postgresql trigger INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger.

I've read the relevant link found here [INSTEAD OF INSERT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/rules-update.html) but I still don't understand what the problem is and even how to attempt to solve it. I have a simple get request, I don't understand why it should not work.

For starters, I have this code in my view.

```
- options = { project_name: contribution.project.url_name,
          committer_name: contribution.contributor_fact.name.name,
          invite: params[:invite] }

%button.btn.btn-primary
   = link_to t('.claim'), one_click_create_account_positions_path(options.merge(account_id: 'me')), { style: 'color: white' }
```

The code hits the get action for `positions#one_click_create` not before going through some before_actions, for finding relevant models.

The one_click_create method is found below.

```
 def one_click_create
  result = current_user.position_core.ensure_position_or_alias!(@project, @name)

  if result.class == Alias
    flash[:success] = t('.one_click_commit_claim', name: @name.name, preferred_name: result.preferred_name.name)
    redirect_to acount_positions_path(current_user)
  elsif result.class == Position
    flash[:success] = t('.one_click_contribution_success', name: @name.name)
    redirect_to accounts_positions_path(current_user)
  end

  flash[:success] = t('.one_click_submit_form', name: @name.name)
  redirect_to new_account_position_path(current_user,
                                      project_name: @project.name,
                                      committer_name: @name.name,
                                      invite: params[:invite])

 end
```

In my particular case the conditional logic is not important. What is important is that when it reaches the final line to redirect to the new_account_position_path, I receive the error as illustrated by this controller test.

```
it 'should successfully redirect to account new page with proper params' do
  position = create_position
  contribution = create(:contribution, position: position)
  get :one_click_create, account_id: 'me', params: { project_name: contribution.project.url_name,
                          committer_name: contribution.contributor_fact.name.name,
                          invite: params[:invite]
  must_redirect_to new_account_position_path(account_id: 'me')
end
```

Can someone help to shed some light on what is the problem here and why it 'cannot insert into view :contributions"'?

Answer (score 1):

A view is a virtual table obtained by executing a query over other real or virtual tables. For this reason a view can be modified *only* in special cases, in particular when it is defined from a single (real) table, and, also in this case, under particular conditions. If your program is trying to insert something into a view which is not defined over a single table, and satisfying those special conditions, PostgreSQL gives an error. Look at the section "Updatable Views" of the PostgreSQL manual http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/sql-createview.html. You can use alternative ways of modifying the (real) tables used to define the view, as explained by the hint in the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Renzo. You see the part that I don't understand is the insertion part. I am making a get request, not a post request to this route. There should be no insertion points in this code.

Comment: I've checked my logs and there is no INSERT statement being executed.

Comment: Is the log reporting statements before or after their execution? In your code, there is a line: `contribution = create(:contribution, position: position)`. Could be that line responsible for the creation of a contribution object?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Yes it is the bothersome line that is causing that. I was checking the development logs. With this, I think the culprits are my factory girl associations.